# Disable radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am developing a form and I need to be able to activate a greyed out section when "yes" is selected and disable it when "no" is selected. It would also be great if the code can be condensed and made simpler.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input:radio[name^='event-type-']").prop( "disabled", true );
    $('#submit').css('color','#ccc');

    $("input:radio[class^='yes-']").click(function() {
        var n= "#"+$(this).parent().attr('id');
        if ($(this).is(':checked')){
            $(n+' input:radio').prop( "disabled", false );
            $('#submit').css('color','#000');
        }

        $("input:radio[class^='no-']").click(function() {
            var n= "#"+$(this).parent().attr('id');
            if ($(this).is(':checked')){
                $(n+' input:radio').prop( "disabled", true );
                $('#submit').css('color','#ccc');
            }else {
                $(n+' input:radio').prop( "disabled", true );
                $(n+' input:radio').prop( "checked", false );
                $('#submit').css('color','#ccc');
            }
        });

    });

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/artboycat/pkt7ws69/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost had it, but you were disabling the yes/no buttons as well and your selectors did not match the `textarea`.

Now for an even simpler code see this [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/09ququh5/):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#submit *').prop( "disabled", true );
  $('#submit *').css('color','#ccc');

  $("input:radio[class^='yes-']").click(function() {
    $('#submit *').prop( "disabled", false );
    $('#submit *').css('color','#000');
  });
  $("input:radio[class^='no-']").click(function() {
    $('#submit *').prop( "disabled", true );
    $('#submit input').prop( "checked", false );
    $('#submit textarea').prop( "value", "");
    $('#submit *').css('color','#ccc');
  });
});
```

What did I change?

- I changed the CSS selectors to match "everything below the element with the id `submit`" (which is your `fieldset`). This excludes your yes/no buttons but includes the previously left out `textarea`.
- When a radio button sends a click event, it is automatically checked, so you don't have to check for `is(':checked')`.
- Similar, your last `else` branch was never called.
- I am now clearing the `textarea` as well.
- I moved your second `click` function outside the first.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed. What if I wanted to apply this to multiple sections that are independent of each other?

Answer (score 1):

Following your code, this may fix it:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input:radio[name^='event-type-']").prop( "disabled", true );
    $('#submit').css('color','#ccc');

   $("input:radio[class^='yes-']").click(function() {
       var n= "#"+$(this).parent().attr('id');
       if ($(this).is(':checked')){
            $(n+' input:radio').prop( "disabled", false );
            $('#submit').css('color','#000');
       }
    });
    
   $("input:radio[class^='no-']").click(function() {
       var n= "#"+$(this).parent().attr('id');
      $(n+' input:radio').prop( "disabled", true );
      $(n+' input:radio').prop( "checked", false );
      $('#submit').css('color','#ccc');
      $("input:radio[class^='yes-']").prop( "disabled", false );
      $("input:radio[class^='no-']").prop( "disabled", false );
      $("input:radio[class^='no-']").prop( "checked", true );
    });

  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="grps" id="grps1">
 
 <input type="radio" name="1" class="yes-1" value=1>yes 
 <input type="radio" name="1" class="no-1" value=2>no

<fieldset id="submit">
<legend>Event Type*</legend>
<ul>
<li>Please check event type that best describes your event</li>
<li>This form must be submitted two weeks prior to event date</li>
</ul>


<input type="radio" value="1" name="event-type-1" id="etype-1" class="input-float-left"><label for="etype-1" class="label-longer">&nbsp;Meeting</label>   
 <br>
<input type="radio" value="2" name="event-type-2" id="etype-2" class="input-float-left"><label for="etype-2" class="label-longer">&nbsp;Seminar</label>  
<br>
<input type="radio" value="3" name="event-type-3" id="etype-3" class="input-float-left"><label for="etype-3" class="label-longer">&nbsp;Panel</label> 
 <br>
<input type="radio" value="4" name="event-type-4" id="etype-4" class="input-float-left"><label for="etype-4" class="label-longer">&nbsp;Training</label>   
 <br>
<input type="radio" value="5" name="event-type-5" id="etype-5" class="input-float-left"><label for="etype-5" class="label-longer">&nbsp;Symposium</label>  
<br>




<input type="radio" value="9" name="event-type-6" id="etype-9" class="input-float-left"><label for="etype-9" class="label-longer">&nbsp;Other</label>
<div id="show-me"><TEXTAREA COLS="60" ROWS="4" name="other_item" id="etype-9" maxlength="80" size="25" class="input"></TEXTAREA></div>  

</fieldset>
</div>
 
 <BR clear="all">
<br>
```

That's not the best way to do it but should works for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[name="1"]').click(function() {
  var value = $(this).val();
  if (value === "2") {
    $('#submit input, textarea').prop('disabled', true);
    $('#submit').css('color', '#ccc');
  } else {
    $('#submit input, textarea').prop('disabled', false);
    $('#submit').css('color', '#000');
  }
});
```

When you click on No (with value 2), it disables all inputs and text areas and changes the font color to grey. When you click on yes (value 1), it enables it and makes the font black.